# Redirect Dynamic Page to Dynamic Page In Different Folder

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301

My current page is set up like this, where '#' is a number for each user;

```
http://site.com/member.php?u=#
```

I want to move it to a different folder on the same site, how would I set up .htacces so when some goes to the page above, they're automatically redirected to this;

```
http://site.com/new_folder/member.php?u=#
```

I have seen a few tutorials that show you how to move say member.php?u=234 to /new_folder/member.php?u-234 - But of course new members are registering all the time and even if they weren't I don't want to have to do that for about 1700 users.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It should be as follows:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^member\.php$ new_folder/member.php [NC,R=301,L]
```

And the initial query string will be automatically appended to the destinaion URL.